# Google Sign-In (silentSignIn) fails to get an ID-Token after one hour after initial sign in

Tags: android, access-token, google-signin

I have the google sign-in workflow integrated into my apps for quite some time now and everything worked fine until about 2 month ago. Users started complaining that they had to sign in every time.

What happens: I can still sign in to my apps with the option "requestIdToken". I get the token and can validate it on my server. When I close the app and start it again I get the same token with the silentSignIn call. So far so good. But when I start my app after an hour after the initial sign in, I get the error code 4 (which means I'm not signed in).

I tried a lot and put my code upside down, but I can't get it working again. When I try the silentSignIn without the requestIdToken, I get a successful sign-in. So the sign in seems to work fine, but somehow I don't get a new token after the initial one expired. I even tried to create a new Web-Client-Id on the API console, but nothing changed.

Here are my simple options and the rest is exactly like the google examples:

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .build();
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

I use com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1

Is there anything important, that I have to configure in the API-console for my Web-Client-ID or any magic permissions that I am not aware of.